# WPF & Prism: RadioButton selection disappears on multiple UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I am using Prism's `InteractionRequestTrigger` in several UserControls to display a notification using my own window content, e.g. `TestControl` containing three `RadioButtons`. In the VM creation time of `TestControl` I set the selection on the 1st radio button.

The problem is, that when displaying the **last** window, the radio button is 
selected like it should be. But all other windows created before do not have any selection. I figured out that my `EnumToBooleanConverter`'s `ConvertBack` function is called and unselects again it when the first radio button of the next user control was selected. And so on... Do you know why? How to solve this?

Here is a simple code to reproduce this issue:

**MainWindow:**

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels" Title="MainWindow">
<StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding StretchModeRequest1}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <local:TestControl/>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>

        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding StretchModeRequest2}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <local:TestControl/>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>

        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding StretchModeRequest3}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <local:TestControl/>
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Button Content="Command 1" Margin="5" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
    <Button Content="Command 2" Margin="5" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
    <Button Content="Command 3" Margin="5" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>

</StackPanel>
```

**MainViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public InteractionRequest<Confirmation> StretchModeRequest1 { get; private set; }
    public InteractionRequest<Confirmation> StretchModeRequest2 { get; private set; }
    public InteractionRequest<Confirmation> StretchModeRequest3 { get; private set; }

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        StretchModeRequest1 = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();
        StretchModeRequest2 = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();
        StretchModeRequest3 = new InteractionRequest<Confirmation>();

        ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnClicked);
    }

    private void OnClicked(object obj)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
        var confirmation = new Confirmation() { Content = "Test", Title = string.Format("Bla {0}", index) };
        switch (index)
        {
            case 1: StretchModeRequest1.Raise(confirmation); break;
            case 2: StretchModeRequest2.Raise(confirmation); break;
            case 3: StretchModeRequest3.Raise(confirmation); break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestControl:**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TestViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<StackPanel Margin="3,3,3,0">

    <RadioButton Margin="2" GroupName="Mode" Content="None" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedMode, 
        diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:StretchType.None}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <RadioButton Margin="2" GroupName="Mode" Content="Limits" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:StretchType.Limits}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton Margin="2" GroupName="Mode" Content="Static" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:StretchType.Static}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**TestViewModel:**

```
public class TestViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private StretchType _stretchMode;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        SelectedMode = StretchType.None;
    }

    public StretchType SelectedMode
    {
        get { return _stretchMode; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _stretchMode, value); }
    }
}
```

**Converter:**

```
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a unique `GroupName` for each view, .e.g.:

```
<RadioButton Margin="2" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Content="None" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:StretchType.None}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<RadioButton Margin="2" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Content="Limits" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:StretchType.Limits}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<RadioButton Margin="2" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Content="Static" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:StretchType.Static}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Excellent! I can go into the weekend ;-) Thank you